# How to merge multiple (more than two) videos on Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, video, vlc, ffmpeg, mencoder

I want to merge videos in batch size of twenty (20) each. I'm running a Linux machine. The videos are in mp4 format and moderate quality. Some even have the audio stream missing. So far I've tried `ffmpeg`, `mencoder`, `cvlc/vlc` and `MP4Box`. I want to write a command line script to achieve this, since I'm doing batch processing.

The main issue is that some of the solutions I tried work well for two videos, some work well for videos with audio stream and yet others work well for some other subset of my video set. However, I have not been able to find a comprehensive solution for this task.

Comment: related ffmpeg subset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg

Comment: See also this even more-popular question: [Stack Overflow: How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333232/4561887)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This solved the matter:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22324018/5014767

`melt` is a great command line utility for this.
[Here](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/MltMelt) is the page

Edit from comments: The command which solved my problem was this
 `melt {input-sequence} -consumer avformat:{output-name} acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264`

Answer (score 84):

I am using `mkvmerge` to join multiple MP4 files into single one:

```
mkvmerge -o outfile.mkv infile_01.mp4 + infile_02.mp4 + infile_03.mp4
```

Comment: It is better to use the extension `.mkv` for the output file, as it is a Matroska container irrespective of what extension you give.

Comment: Here's how to install `mkvmerge`: [tipsonubuntu.com](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/06/27/mkvtoolnix-13-0-0-released-install-ubuntu/)

Comment: Only this command mkvmerge works. All ffmpeg ones fail with shifted audio at least.

Comment: To install `mkvmerge` do `sudo apt install mkvtoolnix`

Comment: This is simple and fast way to merge two `.mkv` files.

Answer (score 55):

You can do it using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:"input1.mp4|input2.mp4" output.mp4
```

[reference and more info](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Concatenating-using-the-concat-demuxer)

Comment: I tried doing that. The issue with this is that it doesn't give a proper out.
1. The audio tracks are muddled.
2. There is some disturbance in the video track.

Comment: I used it for more than sample, the result is high quality,  maybe your source video quality is the problem?

Comment: You are probably right. 
This solved the issue: http://askubuntu.com/a/637179/420614

Comment: Don't use the concat protocol to concatenate MP4. It only works with certain formats that most general users don't encounter. Use [concat demuxer or concat filter](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) instead.

Comment: I tried ffmpeg with 2 mp4 files of 30min each. I got an output file with length 7 hours.

Comment: Use with formats that support file level concatenation (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV). Do not use with MP4. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 43):

Create a file files.txt with all the files you want to have concatenated in the following form (lines starting with a # are ignored):

```
# this is a comment
file 'file1.mp4'
file '/path/to/file2.mp4'
file 'file3.mp4'
```

Note that these can be either relative or absolute paths. Then you can stream copy or re-encode your files:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: `-safe 0` worked for me

Comment: For those having issues merging vids with different widths.. this solution works fine...

Comment: Is it possible to specify in the same files multiple outputs, eg file 'fileA1. mp4' 'A.mp4', 'fileA2. mp4' 'A.mp4', file 'B1.mp4' 'B.mp4',  etc ?

Comment: Life saver alert!

Comment: this ended up working for me but I had to make both the inputs and the output .mkv for it to function. .mp4 would bork the audio.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a little shell script to concat MP4s without transcoding using ffmpeg.

```
for f in $(ls *.MP4); do
    ffmpeg -i $f -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts $f.ts
done

CONCAT=$(echo $(ls *.ts) | sed -e "s/ /|/g")

ffmpeg -i "concat:$CONCAT" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4

rm *.ts
```

This creates intermediate files in an MPEG container and then concatenates them into an MP4.

Comment: It's important to note that this script will fail if any of the filenames contain spaces or, in some cases, special characters. For the loop, it's significantly better to use just `for f in *.MP4` without using `ls`. (You should always avoid using `ls` in scripts for a couple of important reasons; there are better options.) Also, use quotes for variables unless you are _certain_ that there are no spaces or other special characters, so `"${f}"` (or just `"$f"`) instead of unquoted `$f`.

Comment: `CONCAT=$(echo $(ls *.ts) | sed -e "s/ /|/g")` doesn't work well with file names that are 1, 2, 3... 10... 20. It ends up parsing them as 1, 10... 2, 20... etc. I suggest `CONCAT=$(echo $(ls -v *.ts) | sed -e "s/ /|/g")` this will ensure order.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a wrapper around `ffmpeg` called [vidmerger](https://github.com/TGotwig/vidmerger) , which makes it very easy to merge multiple videos inside a folder, for instance to merge all mp4 files inside the current directory, just run:

```
vidmerger .
```

Comment: Works like a charm, built in Rust! I opted to just `cargo build --release` directly from the repo as I needed to use the `-safe 0` option on `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 2):

[LossLessCut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut) works very well for this. Fast and painless.

Comment: I use losslesscut but the result video only working right for firsty 5 minutes. After that images and sound get lagged.

Answer (score 0):

My script, purely in `bash` and `ffmpeg`. Re-encodes files given on a command line into one.

Requires the files to be of the same resolution. Accepts different metadata rotation, which `ffmpeg concat:` doesn't.

```sh
rm ffmpeg-concat-output.mkv

FILE_COUNT=$#
INPUTS=""
FILTER=""
INDEX=0
for FNAME in $@; do
    echo "Processing ${FNAME}"
    INPUTS="${INPUTS} -i $FNAME"

    if [ -z "${FILTER}" ]; then
        FILTER="[$INDEX:v:0] [$INDEX:a:0]"
    else
        FILTER="${FILTER} [$INDEX:v:0] [$INDEX:a:0]"
    fi
    let INDEX+=1
done

COMMAND="ffmpeg ${INPUTS} \
    -filter_complex '${FILTER} \
        concat=n=${INDEX}:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]' \
    -map '[v]' -map '[a]' \
    ffmpeg-concat-output.mkv"

#   -af 'volume=15dB' # won't work with -filter_complex

bash -c "${COMMAND}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Python script](https://lobianco.org/antonello/personal/portfolio/vcat-script) that, using [moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/), can concatenate also subsegments (useful if you want for example remove some parts from a video).

Use it with:

```
vcat -i inputfile1,inputfile2[start-end],... -o <outputfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to throw in my "videomerge" - available for ubuntu via ppa:

Its a QT5 GUI app using drag'n drop. To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jentiger-moratai/mediatools
sudo apt update
sudo apt install videomerge
```

As all of my apps, I try to keep the UI very simple:

[image: 1]

Comment: the repository give me a 404  Not Found error. Do you have a github or sourceforge link?

Comment: You can find it on [github](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoMerge). What is your ubuntu version? Since that repository still exists..

Answer (score -2):

In addition to Maythux's answer, [from](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#toc-Concatenating-using-the-concat-protocol-_0028file-level_0029) :

> A few multimedia containers (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV) allow one to concatenate video by merely concatenating the files containing them.

I.e. the videos to be concatenated use one of the abovementioned video containers (to which I'll add MPEG-4 Part 14 for personal experience), you could simply:

```
cat video1.ext video2.ext video3.ext > video4.ext
```

Comment: I tried this but it only returns the first video as the output. I read somewhere that it doesn't work, though I don't remember the rationale behind this.

Comment: @DhruvSingal Yes, I can confirm this, I've tried this on two MP4 videos with the exact same video / audio encoding and as you I could only browse through the first video. Which seems reasonable, however I'm pretty sure that I've done this before once with a couple of MP4 videos. Perhaps the memory isn't serving well here, or there are other requirements for this to work. I want to research on this since I'm interested also, if I find something I'll update the answer and drop you a comment

Comment: We somehow need to change the metadata at the start of the first video to encompass the entire length of the combined movie, and other stuff probably.  Only a few mpeg4 files let me see the metadata..

Comment: This can't work.