# How to transition smoothly and repeatedly between two videos using a command line tool?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, video, ffmpeg, batch

I want to output a video using two videos as input, where these two videos fade into each other in a smooth and repetitive manner, every second or so.

I believe a combination of `ffmpeg` with `melt`, `mkvmerge`, or another similar tool might produce the effect I'm after. I want to use `ffmpeg` to cut up video A according to a specific interval, discarding every second cut up (automatically). And likewise for video B, although in this case inverting the process to retain the discarded parts.

The file names should be correctly formatted so that I can then concatenate the result using a wild card command argument or batch processing list, as per one of the aforementioned tools. The transition effect isn't absolutely necessary, but it would be great if there were a filter to achieve that too. Lastly, it would also be great if this process could be done without re-encoding, to preserve the original video quality.

I've read through [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637074/how-to-merge-multiple-more-than-two-videos-on-ubuntu/637179?newreg=3eaaf83ec09f4b0b950e31fa2a77b10c) and [the Melt Framework documentation](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/), in addition to the ffmpeg manual, but it's overwhelming.

I'd prefer to find a solution to this problem without having to master each tool. That said, I'm assuming the process might look something like this (but I also think this is likely the wrong approach):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss [magic-argument] output.mp4
```

and then

```
melt {input-sequence} -consumer avformat:{output-name} acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you're just wanting to play them one right after another with no lag between you might try `mpv vid1 vid2` as for actually editing them and splicing, I do not know much about editing software...

Comment: Crossfading requires filtering. Filtering requires re-encoding. However, as j-money suggested, you could use `mpv` as it supports ffmpeg filters and you wouldn't even have to encode anything and it avoids your "without re-encoding" requirement.